# Is there support Redis Search and Redis JSON support in redis-py client

Tags: redis, redis-py, redisearch, redisjson

Is it perform redis search in redis json in redis-py in current version? If yes please provide some sample code? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both RediSearch and RedisJOSN have clients extensions that wrap/extend redis-py see:

- https://github.com/RediSearch/redisearch-py
- https://github.com/RedisJSON/redisjson-py

Notice you can create a redisjson-py client and pass it as an argument to the redisearch-py client.

Comment: Thank you sir answering the question, but i am unable to find  in web, for some  sample example of basic redis search query on redis json in their client(redisearch-py or redisjon-py) ,could you please provide some sample examples.